# SQL - Find the film title and language name of all films in which ADAM GRANT acted

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a ton of trouble thinking in terms of SQL on problems like this.  I don't know how I should be structuring my queries.  Should I be joining `film` on `film_actor` and then join that on `actor`?  Or should I do it the other way around?

[image]

All I've been able to do is get a query that joins `actor` and `film_actor` with the name `ADAM GRANT` but I'm lost on where to go from here.

```
SELECT * FROM (actor JOIN film_actor ON actor.actor_id=film_actor.actor_id) WHERE first_name = 'ADAM' AND last_name = 'GRANT'
```

I've tried doing something to join these results with films, but I'm getting issues with my syntax.

```
SELECT title FROM (actor JOIN film_actor ON actor.actor_id=film_actor.actor_id) WHERE first_name = 'ADAM' AND last_name = 'GRANT' JOIN film ON film.actor_id = actor_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use inner join

```
SELECT 
   film.title
  , language.name
FROM film
INNER JOIN language on film.language_id = language.language_id
INNER JOIN film_actor on film.film_id = film_actor.film_id
INNER JOIN actor on actor.actor_id = film_actor.actor_id
WHERE actor.first_name = 'ADAM'
AND actor.last_name ='GRANT'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NATURAL JOIN`, which removes the range variables (`film_actor`, `actor`) from the query, as well as the 'stating the blooming obvious' search conditions (actor_id = actor_id):

```
  SELECT title AS film_title, name AS language_name
    FROM film 
         NATURAL JOIN film_actor
         NATURAL JOIN actor
         NATURAL JOIN language
   WHERE first_name = 'ADAM'
         AND last_name ='GRANT';
```

I'm not a great fan of the school of thought where a data element such as "name of language" is just called just `name` and the context `language` is supposed to come from the table name. What works well in Java classes doesn't necessarily translate to SQL, which is why I find I need to use a rename in the query (`SELECT name AS language_name...`). Additionally, you have a `name` attribute in `category`, and you would have problems if you ever had `NATURAL JOIN`s including both `language` and `category`. Much better to have unique and consistent attribute names throughout your schema, as you have successfully done with `actor_id`, for example.